# Best way to use Vue 3 components built elsewhere in an ASP.NET project's views?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, webpack, razor, vuex

I'm rewriting some templates and functionality previously developed using AngularJS 1.x which are currently managed and developed as static assets in an ASP.NET MVC application and are used alongside razor syntax (.cshtml). There are no components either. Imagine the AngularJS modules as a huge bunch of jQuery code linked and coupled with views.

This time, I'm implementing everything we need in a Vue 3 app in a separate git repository and I'm also using Vuex 4.

I'm hoping to be able to do the following:

1. Build the Vue app
2. Load the assets in `BundleConfig.cs`
3. Link the assets to my `_layout.cshtml` to have them on all my pages.
4. Use the components wherever I need them.

I'm going well on developing the components and functionalities within its standalone project, yet I'm facing several problems and/or ambiguities.

- I have pages that are mostly if not entirely rendered by the client-side. These pages may or may not be handled by a client-side router such as vue-router.
- I also have pages that are mostly rendered by the server and then stuff is added or dynamic contents are loaded by the client-side. These pages can't use a client-side router.
- I'm not using a router and I'm having a hard time developing and testing those pages that are mostly rendered by Vue.
- if I use a router I think I won't be able to do what I'm planning to do about those pages that are mostly rendered by the server. I really need all pages (whichever kind they are) to have access to my Vuex store.

What do you recommend I do to make it easier for myself both in development and production?

Should I create several static HTML files for each of my pages in Vue's public directory tweak Webpack's configuration in order to simulate what will happen in production (use within the ASP.NET project)?

Should I start having a router, put all pages that are mostly CSR under its control, and somehow configure it to have nothing to do with my other pages that are mostly SSR?

I need to be able to debug and test stuff when I run `npm run serve` and then do what I'm tasked to do. Unless the whole plan is a bad/wrong idea somehow.

I might also be able to build my Vue app as a library and then, in the ASP.NET project, init a small Vue app that imports that library and that itself is bundled with the back-end project. The whole reason I'm doing this is to make the client-side stuff reusable and easy to maintain. I don't want to take a GET SHIT DONE approach.

Thanks